# Why am I getting the error "then is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  //const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  //console.log(result);
  resolveAfter2Seconds.then(function(res) {
    console.log('res');
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('err');
  });
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();
```

I expect the 'then' to be called as a result of the resolve() in resolveAfter2Seconds(), but I'm getting "TypeError: resolveAfter2Seconds.then is not a function" in node.js, and the 'then' is ignored in the browser (chrome).
The commented code is working, but I want to use Promises.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `resolveAfter2Seconds().then(function(res) {...`. you're not calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to run the function.

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  //const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  //console.log(result);
  resolveAfter2Seconds() /*<- here */.then(function(res) {
    console.log('res');
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('err');
  });
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's my foolish mistake. If the javascript interpreter just would have gave me a warning on an error, I could solve it easily.